# Call C# webservices from javascript and consume it (json format)

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I have created a c# webservice and i am trying to call it and consume it from a javascript script, what is the way or the best way to do it, thanks in advance. 
I'll explain more:
this is the web service:

```
 public class DocumentInfo : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetDocumentInfo(string id)
    {
        Document document = new Document(Int32.Parse(id));    
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
        return output;
    }
}
```

I have tested it, it works, when i tried the suggested ajax solutions, i got this error 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Please take a moment to read your question and ask yourself - 'Have I adequately explained myself here?  Have I shown what type of web service I've created and at what point on a web page I want to use it?  Have I shown what I've tried so far to show that I've made an attempt to solve the problem?'

Comment: also vote up:) my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read some of the tutorials

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2010/08/29/calling-an-asp-net-web-service-from-jquery.aspx

```
function TestService() 
{              
    try 
      {

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://webserviceURL.asmx/YourWebMethodName",
         data: "{'abc':'" + 123 + "'}", // if ur method take parameters
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: SuccessTestService,
         dataType: "json",
         failure: ajaxCallFailed
      });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert('failed to call web service. Error: ' + e);
    }
}

function SuccessTestService(responce) {
    alert(eval(responce.d));
}


function ajaxCallFailed(error) {
        alert('error: ' + error);

    }
```

Comment: i get this error 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Vervatovskis this issue i  think is on your server side. check this link http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an AJAX request and wait for the callback to receive the data.

A very simple example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/my_service.cs"
}).done(function(data) { 
  console.log("Received: ", data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery AJAX`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YourServiceURL',
  success: function(data) {
     alert('Web Service Called!');
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i get this error 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Vervatovskis looks like there is an error in the HTTP cycle, sounds like your service is not configured correctly.

Comment: it was a mismatch of call parametr

Comment: Could you, please, specify, what was your problem and how did you solve it (if you still remember)? I am getting the same error, but cannot find any problem in my code...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it... I just needed to add [ScriptService] above the class declaration and [ScriptMethod] above each method I call.

Answer (score 0):

```
go through this demo project it will help you in multiple direction
```

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21045/Different-methods-to-call-Web-Services-from-AJAX

by using javascript ajax method you can do it

```
  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: ,//webservice url
                        data: , // if ur method take parameters
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success:{},
                        dataType: "json",
                        failure: {}
                    });
```